# Propagate exception from async to CoroutineExceptionHandler

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I have an `async` coroutine, that might throw an exception. How can I propagate the exception to my `CoroutineExceptionHandler`? With `try/catch` around `await` I'm able to catch the exception, but I can't seem to propagate the handling to the handler, no matter the context:

```
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> e.printStackTrace() }
val context = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher() + handler
val scope = CoroutineScope(context)

val async = scope.async {
    throw Exception("Test exception")
}
runBlocking {
    try {
        async.await()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        log.error("Exception thrown", e)
    }
    delay(1_000)
}
```

I've tried rethrowing the exception from the catch, or wrapping it with some of the following constructs:

```
catch (e: Exception) {
    throw e
    // withContext(context) { throw e }
    // scope.launch { throw e }
    // supervisorScope { throw e }
}
```

Sadly, none of them propagated it to the handler. Can I somehow utilize `CoroutineExceptionHandler` with `async` coroutines?

Comment: Are you sure you actually need `async`? Your example surely doesn't motivate it, you ignore the result of `await)`. Does your `async` perform a computation whose result you await? Or does it just perform a task? Normally, if you perform a computation in the background, it's because you are doing several computations in parallel and then using their results, all within the scope of a unit of work. In that scenario you'd just use a plain try-catch around that unit of work.

Comment: Yes, my use case is parallel async computation in a flow, and I await the result afterwards to maintain the upstream order. I just wanted to make the example simple, apparently at the cost of higher confusion chance :)

Comment: Couldn't you then wrap all that parallel work in a `coroutineScope`, dealing with any error within it in a single outer try-catch? I think that's how Kotlin wants you to do it, whereas `CoroutineExceptionHandler` is only intended as a last-ditch mechanism to get you informed that, due to a bug in your program, an exception broke out unhandled. It is exactly the strict adherence to this intention throughout the design of Kotlin coroutines that you're having issues using it for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to make it work. First of all, as it's stated in the [async documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html), it cancels the parent job  on failure. That's why `scope.launch { throw e }` does nothing, the scope is cancelled by that time and the coroutine does not even starts.

Then as it's described in the [supervised coroutines documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#exceptions-in-supervised-coroutines), to handle uncaught exceptions in a supervised context, you should install the handler into the child's context. So e.g. the following code will pass the exception to your handler

```
runBlocking {
   supervisorScope {
      launch(handler){
         async.await()
      }
   }
}
```

Another way to go is to install the exception handler into the root scope of your coroutine, e.g. like that

```
runBlocking {
   GlobalScope.launch(handler) {
      async.await()
   }.join()
}
```

Here I'm using `GlobalScope` for demonstration, but it can be any active (non-cancelled) scope.

There are many examples in the [coroutine exception handling doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html) which I'd recommend to check and run also.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

`async` returns a Deferred, which is like a future.  The exception handler doesn’t apply, because if there’s an exception, it is the return value of the Deferred.

From the docs:

> In addition to that, async builder always catches all exceptions and represents them in the resulting Deferred object, so its CoroutineExceptionHandler has no effect either.

source: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#coroutineexceptionhandler